# Problem booting Ubuntu 18.04 from USB on 2012 Macbook Pro

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, mac

I have downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on my 2012 Mac Book Pro and mounted it to two different USB drives using two different softwares: Etcher and unetbootin. When I restart I held down option/alt, and chose the USB. And I got to this screen.

[image: options]

I have chosen every option and I get the same result.

[image: failure]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and could really use some help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The duplicate link above covers the basics of many frequently occurring issues like yours. If none of the worthwhile looking suggestions help please [edit] your question to document what you tried and what happened so we can look at other possible solutions with the knowledge of what *doesn't* work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use third parties… you can use iTerm!
Open the terminal app and then write this, because we need to take the disk identifier of the USB, run the command `diskutil list`

Recognize the pendrive and when your are done, umount the device with the command
 `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX`
*because the system is writing an OS to the pendrive and that requires to umount the drive but don't unplug it!, all data in that USB will be lost.*

Use the `cd` command for entering directories, and the `ls` command for listing all the files that are in your current location, *just remember*.
**In the terminal everything must be written exactly as it is, with the same name and spaces, so use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to avoid mistakes.**
For example, when you start iTerm you should be in your `$HOME` directory, you can prove this by entering the command `pwd`. Now you must reach where did you put your `Ubuntu.iso` file, I'm assuming that is in your `Downloads` folder, so for listing all the folders and files in your home directory just use `ls` and then enter to the folder with `cd Downloads`, so now you're in the Downloads folder, wich is where your `Ubuntu.iso` file is..
*for further info, click [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html)*

Finally use de `dd` utility, so run
 `dd if=ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/diskX bs=8192` 
Wait a few minutes and when it prompts, you're done.

Comment: I am a complete noob to about everything on terminal I've never even run a Linux os before

Comment: I was successful on the first two steps but the last not really sure

Comment: @MagicalAcorns you know the basics of how to use the terminal right?, for making this your Ubuntu iso must be on the location when you enter the command… use `cd` and `ls` for navigating between your files

Comment: I literally know nothing of terminal

Comment: @MagicalAcorns I'm changing the answer for newbies